# Babel-Loader Syntax error on npm run build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I am not very strong with webpack and am trying to update webpack from V3 to V4 and have managed to update my webpack config to the point where its not throwing depreciation errors at me, but I am now stuck on a syntax error from babel-loader:

```
      Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
      /path/react/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/util/hints.js:16
      const currentSchema = { ...schema
      SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

In my webpack config I have this:

```
         test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                  presets: [
                    '@babel/preset-env',
                    '@babel/preset-react',
                    {
                      plugins: [
                        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  compact: true,
                  cacheDirectory: false, // @todo: legacy option: true
                },
              }
            ]
```

and I am using the following versions:

```
 "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
 "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
 "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
 "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
```

I have tried multiple times with diffent versions of babel but always end up at this message. Can anyone see any obvious mistakes I am making?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...` implies that your node isn't transpiling ES6. Have you upgraded node/npm to relatively new versions?

Also, if you're changing versions, I would suggest deleting your `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file before running `npm install` again.

Comment: Thanks, turns out i was using a pretty ancient version of node! On to the next errors...

Comment: @Croot But isn't Babel's job to transpile the syntax, not Node? It is not transpiling because `schema-util` is its own dependency?

Comment: Maybe NodeJS has to interpret ES6 syntax from `schema-utils`(dependency of babel-loader) before BabelJS starts transpilation? I think I get it but can anyone confirm this?

Comment: @user117829 newer versions of node naively handle ES6, as such some modules when referenced from older node versions that do not have the support can throw the above error.