# Solution to 'Uncaught error' - when trying to use Vue JS with Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to create my first Vue component to couple with my laravel mvc application. It's simply a component to use in my 'welcome.blade.php' file.

However, I am getting the following javascript error message in my console, when trying to view the page, and a blank screen:

```
app.js:96 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\util\hints.js:16
  const currentSchema = { ...schema
                          ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:242:18)
    at Module._compile (C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:186:36)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\ValidationError.js:11:5)
    at Module._compile (C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:14:47)
    at Module._compile (C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\index.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:43:25)
    at Module._compile (C:\wamp64\www\client_transactions\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at Object../resources/js/app.js (http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:96:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:20:30)
    at Object.0 (http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:118:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:20:30)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:84:18
    at http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:87:10
```

This happens after completing the following steps to install Vue:

- Navigate to laravel project root and run 'npm install'.
  -Creating the following template:

```
    <template>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Welcome to Vue.js on Laravel
                </div>
                <div class="links">
                    <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">View Laravel Docs</a>
                    <a href="https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/">View Vue Docs</a>
                    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Watch Videos</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        export default {}
    </script>
```

- Updating my resources\js\app.js file to include the following:

  ```
    require('./bootstrap');

    window.Vue = require('vue');

    Vue.component('welcome', require('./components/Welcome.vue'));

    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app'
    });
  ```
- Placing the component inside of my resources/views/welcome.blade.php file:

  ```
        <title>Laravel</title>
  ```

  [...]
- Adding a welcome route in laravel:

  ```
    Route::get('/welcome', ['as' => 'welcome.index', 'uses' => 'home_controller@welcome']);
  ```

If anyone was able to suggest a step that I might be missing, that would be absolutely super.

Comment: I don't use Larvel currently, but this error is related to the fact that your code is not able to understand sets operation (three dot notation), hence when bundling you need babel transcompiler.

Comment: Thanks @Dhaval, wondered if you knew which command to use to install this. I already have node_modules directory.

Comment: Check for babel presets. Its a configuration file for babel which handles this. Are you using laravel mix to handle the compiling ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087421/module-build-failed-from-node-modules-babel-loader-lib-index-js-typeerror

Comment: Following link should work for you.

Comment: Just tried this and still receiving the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152449/babel-loader-syntax-error-on-npm-run-build

Comment: Can you try this ?